# Is ctype_digit() sentitive to the default locale?

Tags: php, locale

I always avoid `ctype_alnum()` because it behaves differently based on the default locale:

```php
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR');

$char = "\xe9"; // LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE (ISO-8859-1)
var_export(ctype_alnum($char)); // true
```

That's why I use `preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/')` instead, because it consistently accepts only ASCII letters, whatever the locale set.

**Is there any kind of similar caveat with `ctype_digit()`?**

Can it allow *any* kind of character outside of the 0-9 ASCII digits?

Answer (score 0):

Edited following @Aziz Saleh comment.

All ctype functions "check whether a character or string falls into a certain character class according to the current locale (see also setlocale())." (from https://secure.php.net/manual/en/intro.ctype.php)

Comment: I don't always trust the PHP documentation, in particular when it *omits* an information. If it was clearly documented that it does *not* depend on the locale, I would definitely trust it, though.

Comment: Agreed @Benjamin but in this case nothing on the documentation or on Google indicated otherwise

Comment: Ctype functions always reflected locale since it's inception.

Comment: @AzizSaleh What should I understand from your comment, regarding `ctype_digit()` specifically?

Answer (score 0):

All `ctype` functions behave the same according to the documentation.

> The functions provided by this extension check whether a character or string falls into a certain character class according to the current locale (see also setlocale()).

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.ctype.php

This means `ctype_digit` might also accept non ASCII digits.

I think the only option is to stick with regular expression or make sure the set the default locale before your code (if it is not variable).